# Navegador no muestra contenido - Ionic

Tags: ionic, angular, api, crud

Pues como dice el título, estoy tratando de consumir una API rest con Ionic 3 y por algún extraño motivo, mi navegador no me muestra el array que regresa la api, lo raro es que en la consola sí se muestra, creí que tenía error de sintaxis o algo parecido en el código pero lo seguí de un tutorial luego lo hice con uno muy distinto y diferente código y da lo mismo, también intenté con otra API y sigue igual, solo se ve en consola, ya intenté con otro navegador y tampoco funciona.

Este es mi código donde llamo la url de la api

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class PrRutasProvider {
 route:any='https://apibancov2.azurewebsites.net/api';
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  }
  get_route(){
   return this.route;
  }

}
```

El método para obtener los datos de la api

```js
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {PrRutasProvider} from '../pr-rutas/pr-rutas';
/*
  Generated class for the PrUsuarioProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class PrUsuarioProvider {
 route_url:any;
  usuario:any;
 constructor(public http: HttpClient, private pr_rutas:PrRutasProvider) {
   this.route_url=this.pr_rutas.get_route();
    console.log('Hello PrUsuarioProvider Provider');
  }
  set_usuario(value){
    this.usuario=value;
  }
  get_usuario(){
    return this.usuario;
  }

  get_todos_usuarios():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.route_url+"/clientes");            
  }
```

El home.ts para posterior mostrar los datos

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {PrUsuarioProvider} from '../../providers/pr-usuario/pr-usuario';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {
   result_usuario:any;
   usuario:any={
     id:''
   }
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public pr_usuario:PrUsuarioProvider) {
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.get_todos_usuarios();
  }
  crear_usuario(){
    this.navCtrl.setRoot('CrearUsuarioPage');
  }
  get_todos_usuarios(){
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad HomePage');
     this.pr_usuario.get_todos_usuarios().subscribe(
        pr_usuario => {
          let data=pr_usuario;
           console.log(data);
           if(data.mensaje=='no hay datos') {
             console.log('no hay datos');
             this.result_usuario=null;
             console.log(this.result_usuario);
           }else{
             this.result_usuario=data.data;
           }
        },
        err => {console.log("NO EXISTE REGISTRO");
        },
      );
  }
```

Y aquí los trato de mostrar pero solo se ven en la consola y no en la vista normal del navegador

```js
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
 <ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of result_usuario">
   <div>{{item.nombre}}</div>
   <div>{{item.apellido}}</div>
   <div>
    <button ion-button (click)="editar(item.id)">Editar</button>
    <button ion-button (click)="eliminar(item.id)">Eliminar</button>
   </div>
  </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
 <button ion-button (click)="crear_usuario()">Crear Usuario</button>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: puedo colaborar en tu git?

Comment: Puedes mostrar lo que te devuelve el log?